# Node JS 404 error with Socket.IO and uploading on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I been stuck on this for hours. I am able to run the code fine locally but when I try to deploy on heroku it throws a 404 error on my socket.

Server code

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = express()
.use(express.static('public'))
.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
const io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
console.log("connection to socket", socket.id);
});
```

Client Code:

```
var socket = io();
socket.emit('email', {
        fullName: fullName.value,
        numOfGuest: numOfGuest.value,
        guestName: guestName.value,
        emailAddress: emailAddress.value,
        guestStatus: status
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps using Socket.io should enable session affinity.

```
heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
```

More about session affinity on heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity